# Tournament play, what would you do?

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament

Pre flop action!

- Blinds **t3000-6000**, 2 players
- Villian#1 is `UTG` and short stack, moves all in for **t75,000**.
- Villian#2 is in `Hijack` position, doesn't realize Villian#1 went all In for $75,000 and verbalized raise and threw out $20,000 chips.
- Poker supervisor makes villain #2 raise the bet to **t150,000**.
- Hero has been noticing Villian#2 open lots of hands, and extra incentive of being forced to raise to $150k is very appealing.
- Hero is on the button with AQ. Hero shoves **t255,000**.

P.S.

If you would like for me to tell you the hands for both players, and result please let me know.

Comment: i removed the `software` tag since your question doesn't have to do with _Poker Supervisor_ ;) About the villain hands, it's better to not inform us to get better answers

Comment: I am assuming hero has 255K, key bit of information needed would be how large is villain # 2's stack. The larger his stack is the more inclined I would be just to let this hand go.

Answer (score 1):

Without the guy being forced to make a raise of much more then he thought, this hand is simple, I am going to raise the all in just to go head up. V1 is not all that short stacked, just short enough to start pushing with some aces or pairs when he can get it in first. His M is about ten, so he is not entirely desperate yet.

Having another player in makes things complicated. I do not like multi-way pots in a tournament, each player in a hand just increases your chances of losing chips. I would tend to muck A-Q when I am third into a raised pot because AQ is a trouble hand in a typical raised pot. However your question is about an exception to the norm.

It is really important to have a little more understanding about V2. How big his stack is important. The ideal situation is that your push will solicit a fold on his part. The higher the likelihood of his folding the more inclined I am to make the move you did. If I am sure he is going to call I may not put my tournament life at risk with your play. There is just a lot of range in the hands these two players will hold, that would leave you broke.

The short stack all in is likely to have an ace or a pair in his hand. The ace in his hand is good for you since his range is any ace at this point so you likely have him dominated. V2 has a wider range, he might have anything, a pair, a crappy ace or the group two and three hands like KJ, nine ten suited and those kind of hands. He is not likely to have a better Ace than you. While your AQ is very strong against most hands they are likely to hold, your chances of losing the hand go way up with two raisers already in the hand.  Your EV is good here, but it is a high risk proposition in a tournament. (I love your play in a cash game)

Bottom line for me is, the more likely V2 is too fold, the better the push is.

Comment: Thank you for a very complete response. Btw villain #2 had 400 k total. I am now seeing my play from a different point of view, and realize that just because I wanted to capitalize on V2s mistake, putting my tournament life on the line vs two players that raised prior to my action is not a winning play overall.

Comment: P.S.    I started day 2 of this two day tourney in 2nd in chips with 363k. I didn't even cash.

Comment: Sorry to be a nuisance with all these individual ?? And comments, but do you think you can explain to me what m is, and how it works.

Comment: M is a short hand for tournament stack sizes, first seen by me used by Dan Harrington in his books. M is the size of your stack compared to the current blinds and antes. If the blinds and antes for example add up to 125 and your stack size is 250, you would have 2 M's. It is a simple way to express your current relative situation rather then spelling out the blind and antes and the relative chip stacks around the tournament table.